# Laravel/Ajax DELETE: "Call to a member function delete() on null"

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller, sql-delete, http-status-code-500

As the title says, I am getting an error when I try to delete my data using laravel/ajax and the function inside the controller:

[image: 1]

**Controller:**

```
public function destroy($category_id) {
    $category_delete = HmsBbrCategory::find($category_id);
    $category_delete->delete();
    return response()->json([
        'status'=>200,
        'message'=>'Category Deleted!',
    ]);

}
```

**Form & Ajax:**

```
`delete_category` is the id that opens the delete modal and `delete_category_btn` is the button that will delete the data.

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block delete_category_btn"></i>Yes</button>
<button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" class="delete_category btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>


        $(document).on('click', '.delete_category', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //click this button(delete_category) to get the value(category_id)
            var cat_id = $(this).val(); 
            // alert(cat_id);
            $('#delete_cat_id').val(cat_id);
            $('#deleteCategoryModal').modal('show');
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.delete_category_btn', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cat_id = $('#delete_cat_id').val();
            // alert(cat_id);
            //token taken from laravel documentation
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-delete/"+cat_id,
                dataType: "dataType",
                success: function (response){
                    // console.log(response);
                    $('#category_notif').addClass('alert alert-success');
                    $('#category_notif').text(response.message);
                    $('#deleteCategoryModal').modal('hide');
                }
            });
        });
```

**Route:**

```
Route::delete('/bbr-category-configuration-delete/{category_id}', [BBRCategoryConfigurationController::class,'destroy']);
```

Things to note:

- I went ahead and showed the category_id inside the modal to prove that the table is getting retrieved.

the the second ajax function for the delete button: `$(document).on('click', '.delete_category_btn', function (e)`, I also tried to show the id using `alert(cat_id);` to also prove that the id is still getting recognized inside the modal:

[image: 2]

Even if category_id is present, inspecting the page after attempting to delete still shows:

```
message: "Call to a member function delete() on null"
```

What can I do to resolve this? thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens if you call `findOrFail()` instead of `find`?

Comment: Check that are you getting ID in controller?

Comment: if you are finding category_id column then it should be  $category_delete = HmsBbrCategory::where('category_id',$category_id)->first();  or else record not there in db.

Answer (score 2):

`$category_delete` object is null. Maybe you are sending a wrong `$category_id`. If you check that the category exists before delete you avoid that error.

```
public function destroy($category_id) {
    $category_delete = HmsBbrCategory::find($category_id);

    if($category_delete) {
        $category_delete->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>200,
            'message'=>'Category Deleted!',
        ]);
    }
    
    return response()->json([
        'status'=>404,
        'message'=>'Category Not Found!',
    ]);
}
```